# How to save images with Node.js

Tags: node.js

The further I go with my blog the more problems I hit :) Can anyone tell me what is the best way to save images. I store the data in mongodb, should I save images in there as well or should I use local file system? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

use file system to store images, free up db resources to serve data. for bigger site images should really use CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Store them in MongoDB using [GridFS](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS).  That way you're not limited by file size, the images are easily shared between multiple app servers, and the images are naturally backed up with the rest of your MongoDB data.